# python-psycopg2: error building sql to insert multiple records when column value contains single quote

Tags: python, postgresql

I am trying to insert some records into a PostgreSQL database. Currently my code generate a list (recordLST) which I loop and generate a tuple, which I add into a different list which is join/converted into a string in order to generate the whole SQL string that will look like:

```
'INSERT INTO table_name ("Column_1", "Column_2", ...) VALUES (...), (...) ON CONFLICT .....
```

Maybe there is a better way of generating the string?

My current code looks something like this:

```
#START THE CONNECTION
connection = psycopg2.connect(host = hostname, 
                        user = username, 
                        password = password, 
                        dbname = db_name, 
                        port = port,
                        connect_timeout=50)  
cursor = connection.cursor()

transaction_SQL = 'INSERT INTO app_banking ("id", "transactionBankDetail_id", "date", "text", "amount", "balance", "typeTransaction", "tags", "oldCategory", "modified_by_id", "exclude_loan" ) VALUES '
sub_value_LST = list()
for x in recordLST:
    thistuple = (x["id"], x["transactionBankDetail_id"], x["date"], x["text"], x["amount"], x["balance"], x["typeTransaction"], x["tags"].replace("'", "\""), x["oldCategory"], x["modified_by_id"], x["exclude_loan"] )
    sub_value_LST.append(str(thistuple))

sub_values = ','.join(sub_value_LST)
transaction_SQL = transaction_SQL + sub_values + ' ON CONFLICT ("id") DO UPDATE SET ("tags", "oldCategory", "modified_by_id", "exclude_loan") = (EXCLUDED."tags", EXCLUDED."oldCategory", EXCLUDED."modified_by_id", EXCLUDED."exclude_loan");' 
print('app_banking\n',transaction_SQL)
try:
    transaction_SQL = transaction_SQL.replace("None", "null")
    a = cursor.execute(transaction_SQL)
except Exception as error:
    return str(error) 
......
```

The above script generates the below string that generally is fine except when the column text has a single quote:

```
INSERT INTO app_banking_transaction 
    ("id", "transactionBankDetail_id", "date", "text", "amount", "balance", "typeTransaction", "tags", "oldCategory", "modified_by_id", "exclude_loan" ) 
VALUES 
    (2419, 2, '2018-11-05', "EFTPOS MANN'S BAKERY AU", '-16.3', -105.33, '', '....', None, None, False),
    (2420, 2, '2018-11-05', 'VISA DEBIT PURCHASE CARD 5044 TT', '-28.15', -89.03, '', '...', None, None, False),
```

If i remove the record for "EFTPOS MANN'S BAKERY AU" it works fine or if i replace the single quote for something like ***, however, I want to try to keep the string as close as possible to what it really is

Do I have to build the query differently, if so how?
or what can i do to the string to make it work as if I escape the string with ', still will not work, getting the error:

column "EFTPOS MANN\'S BAKERY AU" does not exist

Comment: You shouldn't be generating strings.  It seems like you should be using execute_values: https://www.psycopg.org/docs/extras.html#psycopg2.extras.execute_values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Insert/ update records by using `cursor.execute(sql_string, tuple)`, for example you could try the following

```
transaction_SQL = (
    'INSERT INTO app_banking '
    '(id, transactionBankDetail_id, date, text, amount, balance, '
    'typeTransaction, tags, oldCategory, modified_by_id, exclude_loan) '
    'VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s) '
    'ON CONFLICT (id) DO UPDATE SET '
    '(tags, oldCategory, modified_by_id, exclude_loan) = (%s, %s, %s, %s)'
)

for x in recordLST:
    thistuple = (
        x["id"], x["transactionBankDetail_id"], x["date"], x["text"],
        x["amount"], x["balance"], x["typeTransaction"], x["tags"], 
        x["oldCategory"], x["modified_by_id"], x["exclude_loan"], 
        x["tags"], x["oldCategory"], x["modified_by_id"], x["exclude_loan"]
    )
    cursor.execute(transaction_SQL, thistuple)
connection.commit()
```